# Is it wise to merge changes from head to branch?

Tags: svn, merge, branch, head, svn-reintegrate

We decided to make a branch for some feature so we dont affect the head, now the question is it a good idea to keep merging changes from the trunc in our branch? would this meake the reintegrate easier at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Good idea" is too weak, it's a must. The longer life of the branch the more important such merges are.

According to SVN recommendations, at least one merge from trunk to branch should happen right before reintegration. In this case reintegration will be automatic, because you've already resolved any problems in your branch.

For short-lived branches this single merge at the end may be sufficient, but if many things happen on the trunk, it makes sense to synchronize more frequently.

Comment: Thank youfor answering, someone told me SVN would see each merge as new changes which having own revision number and author which does the merge, these would svn try to compare with all changes in trunc on reintegrate. does it really work like this? did you have any experience with this?

Comment: @CloudyMarble: Before version 1.5, there was indeed very limited support of merging. Now you just call merge, resolve conflicts and commit. SVN remembers what has already been merged.

Comment: @CloudyMarble: here it's explained with more details: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.stayinsync